# Draw second bitmap on the first bitmap by method onDraw in Android studio

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, ondraw

I created a customView class which exteds from View. In the method onDraw, I made a canvas and put the bitmap there, then I draw lines and circles on it. I called it in an other class in order to draw it.
Now I need to draw other bitmap on the First Bitmap. When I make another canvas in onDraw and draw the new bitmap there, the application stops working.

```
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Canvas singleUseCanvas = new Canvas();//Canvas in order draw second bitmap
        canvas.drawBitmap(firstBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());
        singleUseCanvas.drawBitmap(roomIconBitmap,100,100,iconPaint); // Second bitmap
         }
```

My question is: how can I draw a bitmap on an other bitmap by onDraw method?
I hope that I could ask my question well. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you draw on the first canvas? onDraw has a Canvas parameter. Why don't you use that?

Comment: I used the canvas parameter in onDraw method, but it causes my app stops. When I draw line or circle it works well. When I want to draw another bitmap on canvas, it does not work.

Comment: If the application stops working? How exactly? You will have exceptions in the logcat?